# getting input string length more than 60

Tags: java, string

I am writing a program calculate the probability of amino acid code in the given sequence. When i try to get the input from the user, it shows the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 407
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at BNC.Sequence.<init>(Sequence.java:50)
    at BNC.Navie_Bayesian_Classifier.main(Navie_Bayesian_Classifier.java:34)
407Java Result: 1
```

My code is

```
      try(Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("F:\\Thiyaga\\ProteinSequence\\Test.txt")))
    {


    line = scan.nextLine().trim();
    length=line.length();
 //   line=reader.readLine();
    }
          System.out.print(length);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        count[i]=0;
        probility[i]='\0';
    }
            for(int k=0;k<length;k++)
    {
        switch(line.charAt(k))
                    {
```

its shows error in at switch or at length

My input is of this form

> MVKETKFYDILGVPVTATDVEIKKAYRKCALKYHPDKNPSEEAAEKFKEASAAYEILSDPEKRDIYDQFGEDGLSGAGGAGGFPGGGFGFGDDIFSQFFGAGGAQRPRGPQRGKDIKHEISASLEELYKGRTAKLALNKQILCKECEGRGGKKGAVKKCTSCNGQGIKFVTRQMGPMIQRFQTECDCHGTGDIIDPKDRCKSCNGKKVENERILEVHVEPGMKDGQRIVFKGEADQAPDVIPGDVVFIVSERPHKSFKRDGDDLVYEAEIDLLTAIAGGEFALEHVSGDWLKVGIVPGEVIAPGMRKVIEGKGMPIPKYGGYGNLIIKFTIKFPENHFTSEENLKKLEEILPPRIVPAIPKKATVDECVLADFDPAKYNRTRASRGGANYDSDEEEQGGEGVQCASQ

Comment: I don't understand where exactly your code is breaking, what is your code completely doing, and which the the line number being talked about.

Comment: Do you modify `String line` within the `for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)` loop? You might as well post the code within that loop.

Answer (score 0):

The execution of the presented code does not result in an error. Here is a reduced version of the given code snippet, that works very well with the given input file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XXX{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    try(Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"))){
      String line = scan.nextLine().trim();
      int length=line.length();
      for(int k=0;k<length;k++)
        System.out.println(k + " " +  line.charAt(k));
     } catch (IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Rather than passing to other class I classified in the same class, with the help of your code. Thanks...